# How to combine _.map and _.filter in a more efficient way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I am using Lodash in my Angular project and I was wondering if there is a better way to write the following code:

```
$scope.new_arr = _.map(arr1, function(item){
    return _.assign(item, {new_id: _.find(arr2, {id: item.id})});
  });
$scope.new_arr = _.filter($scope.new_arr, function (item) {
  return item.new_id !== undefined;
});
```

I am trying to combine values from one array to same objects in other array, and I want to ignore the objects that not appear in both arrays (it is something like join or left outer join in the sql language).

Here is a fiddle with an example of this code: [Click me!](https://jsfiddle.net/Hodor_/wcdgczgz/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i think is better to use chaining

```
$scope.new_arr = _.chain(arr1)
    .map(function(item) {
        return _.merge(
            {}, // to avoid mutations
            item, 
            {new_id: _.find(arr2, {id: item.id})}
        ); 
    })
    .filter('new_id')
    .value();
```

Comment: +1 for the fact that the result is as expected. Have never used chain and merge with Lodash, can you explain what happens here, or at least how chain works? thanks..

Comment: @ValiD about `merge` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge, the common idea of chaining is pass result from previous step(function) to next step to reduce code and so on, but there are negative sides of chaining https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba#.nb3fni346 choose your destiny)

Comment: If use Lodash, this one is best answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/3xjdqsjs/6/

try this:

```
  $scope.getItemById = (array, id) => {
    return array.find(item => item.id == id);
  };

  $scope.mergeArrays = () => {
   let items_with_ids = arr1.filter(item => !_.isNil($scope.getItemById(arr2,item.id)));
   return items_with_ids.map(item => _.assign(item, {new_id: $scope.getItemById(arr2,item.id)}));
  };
```

Comment: Nailed it! I have noticed that you used array functions like find and map rather than lodash functions. Is it more efficient that way?

Answer (score 2):

The answers provided here are all runtime of O(n^2), because they first run an outer loop on the first array, with an inner loop on the second array. You can instead run this in O(n). First, create a hashmap of all the ids in arr2 in a single loop; this will allow us an order 1 lookup. In the second loop on arr1, check this hashmap to determine if those items exist with O(n). Total Complexity is n + n  = 2n, which is just O(n).

```
// provision some test arrays
var arr1 = [
    {
        id: 2
    },
    {
        id: 4
    },
    {
        id: 6
    }
]

var arr2 = [
    {
        id: 3
    },
    {
        id: 4
    },
    {
        id: 5
    },
    {
        id: 6
    }
]

// First, we create a map of the ids of arr2 with the items. Complexity: O(n)
var mapIdsToArr2Items = _.reduce(arr2, function(accumulator, item) {
    accumulator[item.id] = item;
    return accumulator;
}, {});

// Next, we use reduce (instead of a _.map followed by a _.filter for slightly more performance.
// This is because with reduce, we loop once, whereas with map and filter, 
// we loop twice). Complexity: O(n)
var combinedArr = _.reduce(arr1, function(accumulator, item) {

    // Complexity: O(1)
    if (mapIdsToArr2Items[item.id]) {
        // There's a match/intersection! Arr1's item matches an item in arr 2. Include it
        accumulator.push(item);
    }
    return accumulator;    
}, []);

console.log(combinedArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first make a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with `arr1` and then map the items of `arr2` with the properties of `arr1`.

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: 1, title: 'z' }, { id: 2, title: 'y' }, { id: 3, title: 'x' }, { id: 4, title: 'w' }, { id: 5, title: 'v' }],
    arr2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'b' }, { id: 3, name: 'c' }, { id: 4, name: 'd' }, { id: 5, name: 'e' }],
    map = new Map(arr1.map(a => [a.id, a])),
    result = arr2.map(a => Object.assign({}, a, map.get(a.id)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice.. didn't think about the Set option.. In your solution I am missing the 'name' fields. I want to add the objects with the same id to my 'new_arr' under another field. I know it seems like multiplication of fields, but this is only an example of what I really need